# PHP controller code

Tags: php, variables, session-variables

I have a simple HTML page that has a login style. When a submit button is pressed, a PHP script is run and the PHP script gets values and sets the following threesession variables:

```
$_SESSION['userName']
$_SESSION['level']
$_SESSION['score']
```

After these variables have been set. I am wanting to load another PHP script and 'carry' these variables into this new script to be used.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: What's the actual problem? Session will work fine.

Comment: are you using any frame work for php??

Answer (score 0):

At the top of the new page,

```
session_start();

print_r($_SESSION); //put conditionals, loop or different codes.
```

Do whatever you want to do with those values.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest creating a new class and then passing these as parameters. Alternately you could make these global variables but this would be bad practice. Do you know how to do this? If not I will write some sample code.

Here is a great example:

```
class Foo {
    function Foo($init_parameter) {
        $this->some_parameter = $init_parameter;
    }
}

// in code:

$foo = new Foo("some init value");
```

Comment: how he will pass this value to a different page?

Answer (score 0):

These variables are `SESSION` variables so they will be available anywhere on your website providing you have `session_start()` at the top of your page. So 'carrying' them into a new script is not an issue.

If you just want to redirect the user to a new page you can use

`header('Location: newLocation.php');`